# How do I deploy a non-React app on Netlify?

Tags: netlify

I've deployed sites on Netlify before so I know how to use the website. The only difference is that those sites were created via React.js. The website I'm trying to deploy is an old project of mine but I didn't use React at the time so it couldn't be opened using "npm start" "npm build" etc.

So how do you deploy a site that doesn't use React into Netlify? I tried looking for answers online but I couldn't find the specific answer that relates to mine.

Comment: Netlify has nothing to do with React, it can build and host nearly any framework of site.

What is the framework you used previously, what are the build steps, and how does it output the code?

Answer (score 1):

Netlify has nothing to do with React, it can build and host many different types of site with various frameworks.

When [configuring](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/get-started/#definitions) your Netlify site, you can set the following options:

- **Base directory**: Optional field to set the directory that the buildbot changes to before starting a build. If not set, the base directory defaults to the root of the repository.
- **Build command**: If you are using a static site generator or other build tool, this is where you should specify the command to run to build your site. For example, npm run build.
- **Publish directory**: Directory that contains the deploy-ready HTML files and assets, either generated by the build step or pre-built.